# How do I have Splinter to iterate clicks on dropdown menu with python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to gather some yearly stats from http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/stats

The years are on dropdown menu (default selection is 52-weeks).
I succeeded at opening the drop down menu, but my code does not select any year.

```
browser = Browser('chrome')
browser.visit("http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/stats")
window = browser.windows
window.is_current = True
print("asf")
print(browser.find_by_css(".dropdown-label"))
browser.find_by_css(".dropdown-label").click()
print(browser.find_by_css("ul.dropdown li"))
print(browser.find_by_css("ul.dropdown #2015"))
browser.find_by_css("ul.dropdown li")[1].click()
#browser.find_by_css("ul.dropdown #2015").click() Does not work, either.
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
browser.find_by_id("52weeks").first.click()
browser.find_by_id("2010").first.click()
```

Comment: you might need to add a delay in between the 2 clicks ... ```import time; time.sleep(2)``` for a 2 second delay